# jQuery show / hide elements based on *multiple* jQuery UI sliders

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-filter

I'm trying to create an airline style time filter.

I have a series of 'badges', each with a series of times in seconds:

```
<div id="block732914299" class="pull-left" data-departuretime1="1340" data-departuretime0="865" data-arrivaltime0="980" data-arrivaltime1="10">
```

Now I want to use the jQuery UI sliders to show/hide various badges based on these times.

I have one working.

```
$(".slider-range1").slider({
    range: true,
    min: mintime,
    max: maxtime,
    step: steptime,
    values: [mintime, maxtime],

    slide: function (e, ui) {
        var time2 = moment().startOf('day').add('m', ui.values[0]).format('h:mma');
        var time3 = moment().startOf('day').add('m', ui.values[1]).format('h:mma');
        $('.slider-time2').html(time2);
        $('.slider-time3').html(time3);

        // show or hide badges based on attr for each badge
        $('div[id^="block"]').each(function(e){
            if($(this).data('arrivaltime0') >= ui.values[0] && $(this).data('arrivaltime0') <= ui.values[1]){
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide()
            }
        });
    }
}); // slider-range1
```

But I'm a bit stuck when I add the second slider because now they are conflicting. When I alter one slider it overrides the other.

Digging through the jQuery docs I'm looking at .filter - but I'm not sure how best to proceed using that.

I can probably write a bunch of ugly if/else statements to check all the permutations but it seems like there should be a more efficient way to do this?

**Update:**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thecrumb/FB4Sv/27/

Use/test case:

- Set departure slider to 7-9AM - Badge A and B should display (8am)
- Without changing first slider, set arrival slider to 7-9PM - Badge C should display (8pm)
- At this point Badges A, B AND C should be displayed.
- D should still be hidden.

Still stuck with this :(

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: @j08691 I updated my question and added a jsFiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

is it an AND or an OR situation?

Assuming it's OR you could do something like this...

FIRST you hide them all. THEN you show the applicable ones for each slider

```
// show or hide badges based on attr for each badge
$('div[id^="block"]').hide().each(function(e){
    if($(this).data('arrivaltime0') >= ui.values[0] && $(this).data('arrivaltime0') <= ui.values[1]){
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

If you wanted AND you just do the opposite. show them all then hide the invalid ones

```
// show or hide badges based on attr for each badge
$('div[id^="block"]').show().each(function(e){
    if(! ($(this).data('arrivaltime0') >= ui.values[0] && $(this).data('arrivaltime0') <= ui.values[1])){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

The problem with your current code is that it is showing or hiding every element every time so the different sliders are stepping on eachother.

Comment: Ah ha! I think this will work!  Thanks for the quick solution using my existing code.

Comment: Well I thought this might work but testing it - it still behaves the same way.  I select 8am with the first slider - it correctly filters to show only the 8am blocks. But when I adjust the second slider so it shows 2pm blocks - the 8am blocks are hidden.

Let me see if I can hack up a fiddle example.

Comment: oh... yea. because it re-hides everything. *facepalm*

Comment: You  need to make a method that ALL sliders call that does ALL of the processing at once. I'll update one second.

Comment: Fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/thecrumb/47yDB/10/

So if I filter by departure: 7-9AM I should see Blocks A/B. And if I filter by arrival: 9-10PM I should see block C.

So I should have A,B,C and not D displayed. But it's A,B or C.

Comment: @JimPriest I don't follow your question, but did you see my other answer?

Comment: You example makes sense.  I cleaned up your example a bit but it doesn't work .   If I comment out either of the slider1 or slider2 checks in doShowHideBadges it works for that slider, but combining the two doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/thecrumb/FB4Sv/14/

Comment: @JimPriest The logic was just backwards. I updated the code in the other answer please select it as the correct answer if it's working. Thanks. Also updated this: http://jsfiddle.net/FB4Sv/17/

Comment: @kenny That's closer.  Seems like I need an "AND" between the two if statements if that makes sense.  
  
My test case: 
- Set departure sliders to 7-9 AM - Block A and B should display
- Set arrival sliders to 7-9 PM - Block C (along with Block A/B) should display

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated answer using a function. I just figured I'd create a new answer to make it cleaner...

```
$(".slider-range1").slider({
    range: true,
    min: mintime,
    max: maxtime,
    step: steptime,
    values: [mintime, maxtime],

    slide: function (e, ui) {
        var time2 = moment().startOf('day').add('m', ui.values[0]).format('h:mma');
        var time3 = moment().startOf('day').add('m', ui.values[1]).format('h:mma');
        $('.slider-time2').html(time2);
        $('.slider-time3').html(time3);
        doShowHideBadges();         
    }
}); // slider-range1

function doShowHideBadges(){
    //show all initially then loop through and hide each invalid option
    $('div[id^="block"]').show().each(function(e){
       //show items for first slider
        var sliderValue = $('.slider-range0').slider("option", "values");
        if($(this).data('departuretime0') < sliderValue[0] ||
           $(this).data('departuretime0') > sliderValue[1]){
           $(this).hide();            
       }
       // show items for second slider
       var slider2Value = $('.slider-range1').slider("option", "values");
       if($(this).data('arrivaltime0') < slider2Value[0] ||
          $(this).data('arrivaltime0') > slider2Value[1]){
           $(this).hide();           
       }

    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FB4Sv/17/

Comment: I'm so close... :)    

  http://jsfiddle.net/thecrumb/7Err4/1/  

This works *IF* you move both sliders.  Somehow I need to add a check to see if either slider has been moved.